# Conditional Expectation (Problems)

Tags: probability-theory

I have the next definition: Let $Y:(\Omega,\mathcal{A})\to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ and $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{A})\to (\Omega',\mathcal{A}')$ be random variables; $E(Y|X)$ is the random variable such that, for all $A'\in \mathcal {A}'$
$$\int_{X^{-1}(A')} Y(\omega) \ d P(\omega) = \int_{A'} E(Y|X)(u) \ d P^X(u),$$
and if $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$, is a $\sigma$-algebra, $E(Y|\mathcal{B})$ is the random variable such that, for all $B\in \mathcal {B}$
$$\int_{B} Y(\omega) \ d P(\omega) = \int_{B} E(Y|\mathcal{B})(u) \ d P(u).$$

The problem is that I don't know how use that for solve problems. For example, I have these exercises:

- Find $E(X|A)$, where $P(A)>0$ (I thing that $E(X|A)=E(X|1_A)$).
- Find $E(X|\mathcal{G})$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the partition $(A_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$.
- Prove $E((Y-E(Y|\mathcal{B}))^2)=E(Y^2)-E(E(Y|\mathcal{B}))^2$.
- Let $g$ be a convex function, $g(X)\in L^1$, prove $g(E(X|\mathcal{B}))\leq E(g(X)|\mathcal{G})$.

How could I start?

Comment: Are you sure you want $dP^X(u)$ for the definition of ${\bf E}[Y\mid \mathcal{B}]$ instead of $dP(u)$?

Comment: I fixed it, thanks @user139388

Comment: The first displayed identity in the question is flawed since $P^X$ is a measure on the target set of $X$ while $E(Y\mid X)$ is a random variable on the source set of $X$ hence the RHS makes no sense.

Comment: Which textbook are you following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the first one, note that 
$\sigma(1_A) = \{\emptyset, A, A^c, \Omega\}$, so for $G \in \sigma(1_A)$, $G \neq \emptyset$
$$
  \int_G {\bf E}[X \mid 1_A] dP
= \int_G X dP
= {\bf E}[X 1_G]
= \int_G \frac{1}{P[G]}{\bf E}[X 1_G] dP,
$$
thus 
$$
  {\bf E}[ X \mid 1_A]
= \frac{1}{P[A]} {\bf E}[ X1_A]1_A + \frac{1}{P[A^c]} {\bf E}[ X1_{A^c}]1_{A^c}.
$$
You can see that this generalizes to the second case, where if $P[A_i]>0$ for all $i$ then 
$$
  {\bf E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}]
= \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{P[A_i]}{\bf E}[X1_{A_i}]1_{A_i}.
$$
Does this help to get you started for the rest?

Comment: I don't understand why $\int_G {\bf E}[X \mid 1_A] dP
= \int_G X dP$. And then ${\bf E}[ X \mid 1_A]
= \frac{1}{P[A]} {\bf E}[ X1_A]1_A + \frac{1}{P[A^c]} {\bf E}[ X1_{A^c}]1_{A^c}$.

Comment: @AndrésMerino The definition of ${\bf E}[X \mid Y]$ is that it is a $\sigma(Y)$-measurable random variable satisfying 
$$
  \int_G {\bf E}[X \mid Y] dP
= \int_G X dP
$$
for all $G \in \sigma(Y)$.